# Есть ли более простой способ заставить ввод с клавиатуры возвращать символ в SFML c#?

Tags: c#, sfml

Я хочу использовать ввод с клавиатуры. Я пытаюсь получить ввод с клавиатуры, который возвращает символ: нажатая клавиша.

Есть ли лучший способ сделать это?

```
public char getKey() 
{
    if (Keyboard.isKeyPressed(Keyboard.key.A))
    {
        return 'A';
    } 
    if (Keyboard.isKeyPressed(Keyboard.key.B))
    {
        return 'B';
    }
    if (Keyboard.isKeyPressed(Keyboard.key.C))
    {
        return 'C';
    }

    ...

  
}
```

Comment: А зачем это? Если надо проверить, нажата ли конкретная клавиша, просто проверяете и всё. В чём смысл таких преобразований? А для ввода можно написать что-то типа `TextField` https://stackoverflow.com/a/53765163/12888024

Comment: Большое спасибо